# Difference between 行き先 and 行く先

Tags: nuances

What is the difference between 行き先 and 行く先? It seems like 行く先 has a slightly broader meaning (it is also about the road to the destination?) but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- 行き先（いきさき） is a mundane word meaning "destination (e.g., of a bus, trip)". Some people say ゆきさき, which is a variation of this.
- 行く先（ゆくさき） sounds a bit literary. In lyrics, poetry and stiff novels, 行く先 is semantically identical to 行き先. If this word appears in casual speech, it would mainly refer to "future (e.g., of a child, project)" in modern Japanese. In this sense, synonyms include 行く末（ゆくすえ） and 将来.

> - 電車の行き先を確認する。
> - 会社の行く先が心配だ。